# how to minimize trace(mod(A*X,2)) for A ,X matrices

Tags: matrices, algorithms, finite-fields, discrete-optimization

I have a constant binary matrix $A$ (entries $0$ or $1$) and an unknown matrix $X$ which is also binary. I'd like to find $X$ that minimizes $trace(mod(A*X),2))$. So basically I do a matrix multiply of $A$ and $X$ as if they are over finite field GF(2), that's what the $mod(*,2)$ is doing, but I want the trace over the integers. The $mod$ operation creates problems for all what I tried. Any suggestions on how to do this?  ($X$ is constrained to be an invertible matrix over GF(2))

Comment: Perhaps I haven't understood, but if you're choosing $X$ to minimize the trace, couldn't you just pick $X$ to be the zero matrix?

Comment: @Brantley good point. $X$ has to be an invertible matrix and the actual problem i'm working on has $A^T X A$ instead of $A X$...I tried to simplify the question but I'll edit to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may use elementary column operations to bring $A$ to column reduced echelon form. This, in particular, implies that for some invertible matrix $X_1\in GL_n(GF(2))$, we have
$$
AX_1=\pmatrix{I_k&0\\ \ast&L}
$$
where $L$ is a lower triangular matrix with a zero diagonal ($I_k$ is void if the first row of $A$ is zero; $L$ is empty and $AX_1=I$ if $A$ is invertible). Now let $C$ be the $k\times k$ permutation matrix for a cyclic shift and
$$
X_2=\pmatrix{C\\ &I_{n-k}}.
$$
Then
$$
AX_1X_2=\pmatrix{C&0\\ \ast&L}
$$
has a zero diagonal. Hence its integer matrix reincarnation also has a zero diagonal and a zero trace.

Comment: Good answer! I was only expecting a general procedure to turn the problem into something a general purpose integer linear programming package can handle; this is a direct solution which is better for this particular problem. I'm also interested in minimizing $sum(sum(A^T X A))$ (the number of ones on $A^T X A$). I'll ask a separate question for that